# How to put char in setter in Java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I'm trying to make a Calculator, so I have this Calculator.java and CalculatorTest.java using setters and getters.

```java
public class Calculator {
  
    private int a;
  
    public int getA() {
      return a;
    }
    
    public void setA(int calcOneA) {
       this.a = calcOneA;
    }
  
    private int b;
    
    public int getB() {
      return b;
    }
    
    public void setB(int calcOneB) {
       this.b = calcOneB;
    }
        
    private char sign;
  
    public char getSign() {
      return sign;
    }
    
    public void setSign(char calcOneSign) {
        this.sign = calcOneSign;     
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calcOne = new Calculator();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите первое число");
        calcOne.setA(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Введите знак математической операции");
        calcOne.setSign(nextLine());
        System.out.println("Введите второе число");
        calcOne.setB(scanner.nextInt());
      }
}
```

I don't know how to put math sign into `calcOne.setSign()`. I tried `nextLine()` but it says can't find symbol.

Comment: Do you mean `scanner.nextLine()`? If you want a character from that, you can do `charAt(0)`.

Comment: I am not sure what your expecting...please check this whether it helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-signum-method-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't the setter.

For example, you can call `calcOne.setSign('a');` on its own.

Now, to reproduce that for user input, you need to fix your scanner usage, for example

```
calcOne.setSign(scanner.nextLine().charAt(0));
```

However, if you're typing something like `2 + 2`, the `+` is called the operator, and it's not always a specific index within the string (if you type this on its own line, it might be okay)

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` returns a string, so you must extract the first character:

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
// check that s has one and only one character.
calcOne.setSign(s.charAt(0));
```